# Will CSS 3 still allow omitting final semicolons?

Tags: css

There seems to be a breaking (i.e. backwards-incompatible) change in the CSS Syntax Module Level 3 specification upcoming draft: trailing semicolon after the last declaration in a block is now perhaps required.

Compare the old wording ([W3C Working Draft 13 August 2003](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#rule-sets)):

> 4.8. Rule sets, declaration blocks, and selectors
>   A declaration-block (also called a {}-block in the following text) starts with a left curly brace ({) and ends with the matching right curly brace (}). In between there must be a list of zero or more semicolon-**separated** (;) declarations.

with the new one ([Editor's Draft 14 June 2012](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-syntax/#syntax-description)):

> 2. Description of CSS's Syntax
>   A rule starts with a selector (defined by the Selectors specification), then has a {}-wrapped block containing a sequence of declarations. The selector specifies which elements the declarations will apply to. Each declaration has a property name, followed by a colon and the property value, and **finished** with a semicolon.

(emphasis mine).

So that nifty short forms, e.g.:

```css
em { color: lime }
```

(this is currently given as valid example in the CSS Color Module Level 3 recommendation) will no longer validate.

Could someone more knowledgeable about the whole Level 3 drafts collection please verify? To future-proof stylesheets, do we really have to overhaul existing CSS files (and insert semicolons if missing) before the specification gets finalized or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Fun fact: The last code of [example 2](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-syntax/#at-rules) in the editor's draft omits the final semicolon: `body{font-size: 10pt}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there currently is an ambiguity in the spec.

You correctly pointed out that [2. Syntax Description section](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-syntax/#syntax-description) prescribes ending every rule with a semicolon:

> Each declaration has a property name, followed by a colon and the property value, and finished with a semicolon.

And at the same time, description of the parsing automaton in section [3.6.8. Declaration-value mode](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-syntax/#declaration-value-mode) reads that a closing brace without a semicolon correctly ends a declaration and current rule at the same time:

> *} token*
>
> Append the current declaration to the value of the current rule. Pop the current rule from the stack of open rules, and append it to the value of the new current rule. Switch to the current rule's content mode.

So according to *3.6.8* trailing semicolon is optional.

I can't say about actual intention of the specification authors. But current situation should probably be reported and fixed. Most certainly they don't have intention of breaking the compatibility with CSS 2.1 and will reword their *Syntax Description* section in the final version.

Comment: Thaks for pointing out parser details. But I suppose you intended to cite the **} token**, not the semicolon token (required or not, `;` would obviously complete a declaration either way). Should I use the [www-style@w3.org](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/) mailing list to report this ambiguity? Despite the [claim](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work#contribute) that _everybody_ can take part in the discussions, the list appears to be rather elite.

Comment: @heapunderrun Thanks for your correction, I edited the answer. Yes, it would be good if you wrote to the mailing list if you have time. Though I would do it myself in a week (I'm a bit busy now with my university graduation).

Comment: @NichtVerstehen Did the W3C ever clarify their stance on this?

Answer (score 5):

I think that it's just a mistake when writing the specifications, and that the real intention was to have it as a separator, just as in previous versions. I expect this to be adjusted in later drafts.

The [W3C validation service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) says that the example without the trailing semicolon is valid CSS level 3.

I will however, as I have always done, end each declaration with a semicolon. This is a good practice, so that you don't forget the separator when you add more declarations.

Comment: Nothing more annoying than refreshing the page and going "WTF? Y U NO WORK!"

Comment: I wouldn't rely on Validation Service recognizing _recent changes_, esp when dealing with fundamental changes in parsing. I remember the time when W3C's official XHTML validator wasn't able to process UTF-16 and instead barked an error at every character in the input file. This remained unfixed for a long time.

Furthermore, there's a catch. In the _Valid CSS information_ secton, W3C's validator not only just auto-indents but also silently inserts trailing semicolons (as if these were initially present)! This is confusing, you can't use the _Validate by file upload_ to spot missing semicolons.

Comment: @heapunderrun: If the parsing would really change from using semicolon as a separator into using ending semicolons, that would be a *major* change in the syntax, making *a lot* of current CSS markup incompatible with CSS 3. If there really was such a case, I think that it's very likely that they would make the validation service validate it correctly.

Comment: Should be noted that it's been 9 years since these comments and the W3C validator still does not flag missing semicolons as an error. I'm not sure what their official stance is, but at this point it seems like the trailing semicolon is 100% optional.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the 'separator-terminator' problem. Evidently CSS 3 has moved from the semicolon being a separator to the semicolon being a terminator. That means it is required after every element, not just between the elements. Pascal (separator) and C (terminator) provide other examples. This leads to apparent anomalies in Pascal such as semicolon being illegal before 'else' or 'until'. Why CSS 3 adopted a CSS-2-incompatible rule is beyond me, and whether implementations will insist on it is another matter, but the intent of the quotation is clear: it's a terminator and must therefore be present on all entries including the last.