# CSS cursor property isn't working

Tags: css, cursor

I'm trying to set a cursor to all the tags `<a>` but when I look at the website the property isn't showing

**CSS**

```
 a {
  color: #333333;
  /* color: #787878; */
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer
 }
```

**On the website**

```
 a {
  color: #333333;
  /* color: #787878; */
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

if you wanna give a look the website is: [backlabel.com](http://backlabel.com)

Comment: From what I can see you have no ; after pointer. Also <a> tags with a href are pointer by default.

Comment: @Paulie_D ok fixed thank you

Comment: @David i tried but it doesn't work and yea but those <a> don't, idk why, so i'm trying to specify it but it doesn't save the changes

Comment: What browser are you using? I get a pointer in Chrome. & FF on Windows

Comment: I also get pointers.

Comment: @Paulie_D I also get the pointer if i add it on the inspector but when i apply it on the css it doesn't appear

Comment: @David you don't need to terminate the last declaration with a trailing semi-colon, it's optional as far CSS 3 is concerned - but still considered good practice. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062615/will-css-3-still-allow-omitting-final-semicolons

Comment: @RachelS read the answer i gave Paulie_D thank you

Comment: I also get pointers in the above browsers opera and internet explorer on Windows. Is there a specific page I should look at?

Comment: Since I get pointers and you don't...what do **you** get?

Comment: @Paulie_D i get "text" as default instead of pointer

Comment: I see the pointers without having to do anything. As David pointed out, the pointer should be there automatically unless you disabled them.

Comment: @David any product page is fine but as i said it doesn't apply the changes only when i put it in the css

Comment: ...in what broswer and which **specific** link?

Comment: When I view the site (2nd time today, first for a `z-index` issue) I see the rules you've provided above with `cursor: pointer` declared for `a` in global.css line 421. Are you sure it's simply not a caching issue?

Comment: Try cursor: pointer !important; to overide

Comment: @RachelS i tried on Chrome and Safari but still i get text instead of pointer and only those 2 <a> have this problem the others work fine

Comment: Give us a Specific page and link plz

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError yea i started working on it only when he closed it

Comment: @jmercier Agreed, it's getting dark in here and we're all holding knives.

Comment: @jmercier i tried !important but nothing and this is the page i'm looking at (i'm sorry  i don't understand how to put a link)http://www.backlabel.com/forward/207-cropped-leggings-performance-cotton.html

Comment: @Marwane Every link I see on that page has the rule you've declared. Is there a specific element/link we need to be regarding?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError yes the "care & washing" e "composition"

Comment: @Marwane Still see those rules you've declared in global.css:421 even on those elements.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError then now I'm confused about why only i can't see it

Comment: @Marwane It could be something very specific to your local working environment. Have you ruled out any possible browser extensions that could affect page links in any sort of way? Is this issue replicated on other PCs (do your coworkers experience the same issue)? Make sure it's not some sort of persistent local caching at work there. You might want to clear any browser cookies associated with this as well.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError ok i'll try as soon as possible. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Marwane The process of elimination, Marwane, you should come right.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your link **isn't a link** at all.

The HTML is:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Care &amp; Washing&nbsp;▾</a>
```

If a "link" doesn't have a `href` it's not a link, it's treated as, essentially, a span.

Since you are using this as "toggle" you could add

```
a[data-toggle] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Declaring a `cursor:pointer` on this element regardless of an `href` attribute being present or not will still alter the cursor state. You could change the element to a `span` and still make it look like a link by declaring this rule. The end user would be none the wiser.