# Leaving off closing delimiters in CSS

Tags: css

I have noticed that in a CSS rule, I can leave off the last semicolon and it still works:

```
p {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px
}
```

Also, if I am commenting out something at the end of an inline style, I can leave off the closing `*/` and it still works:

```
<p style="color:red;/*font-style:italic">Red</p>
```

Is this valid syntax, or is it just the web browser gracefully handling my messy code?

Comment: Go find out: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: See [this related Stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939595/leaving-out-the-last-semicolon-of-a-css-block).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062615/will-css-3-still-allow-omitting-final-semicolons